# What exactly happens to Prarabhdha karma while performing "Yoganidra" in Meditation?

Tags: practice, karma, yoga, meditation

I came across a term "Yoganidra" in one of spiritual book. And I came to know that "Yoganidra" can experience during Meditation.

My questions are:

- What is the meaning of "Yoganidra"? Are there any Types of "Yoganidra"? Briefly
- How to perform "Yoganidra"? Can I get a spiritual reference for it?
- Can we perform "Yoganidra" by Own or Does we need a spiritual "GURU" for this?
- What exactly happens to Prarabhdha karma while performing "Yoganidra" in meditation?
- What is the significance of "Yoganidra" in Spiritual Growth (Adhyatmik pragati) of a sadhaka?
- Are there any benefits doing "Yoganidra"?

And I found that "Yoganidra" is different from sleep.

- Is it means that we can't experience "Yoganidra" while sleeping? If Yes/No How to know it?

Comment: This contains all information you might need to know about Yoga Nidra. http://www.yogamag.net/archives/2005/emay05/yn.shtml Thanks for asking this question sir. As with any yogic practice, it is best to practice under Guru's watchful vision. God will ensure you do it right :). Yoganidra is neither sleeping nor wakefulness, it is conscious sleep (as per my understanding of the link above atleast!!) All the best!!

Comment: Thanks for the Link, but still few more questions need to be clear...:):).

Answer (score 3):

Yoga nidra is another way of expressing what in Patanajali's Yoga Aphorisms is called Dharana and Dhyana - steadfast concentration and meditation.

See also Gita Chapter 6, The Way of Meditation.

To get the best results for these requires the guidance of one's Guru. It can be dangerous to go too deep without the Guru.

The significance to a sadhaka is that (in conjunction with the other steps of yoga called Yama) it purifies the heart. When the heart is purified, one can see the Lord. Swami Vivekananda said "Control the mind, cut off the senses, then you are a Yogi; after that, all the rest will come..."

What it means by burning away one's karma is this - perhaps your karma was to have a severe accident with a large life threatening wound. Instead, as a result of burning away your karma in meditation and japam, you have the accident, but instead of the large wound you get a pinprick only. You cannot escape your karma, but you can lessen it's effects.

Comment: If we can only lessen our karma and their karmic effects then how can a jeeva become jeevan mukta to get mukti from all of his karma??. Even in some shlokas like sahastranaam it is written that whosoever reads this sahastranaam gets moksha after dehavasan(end of material life).

Comment: @Creator Svetasvatara Upanishad (VI. 4.) says: "He who attains purity of heart by performing actions as an offering to the Lord, and merges prakriti and all its effects in Brahman, realizes his true Self and thereby transcends phenomena. In the absence of maya, both collective and individual, all his past actions [except the prarahdha] are destroyed [and he becomes liberated though still in the body]. After the destruction of the prarabhda karma he attains final Liberation." See also Gita IX. 27-28., V. 10-11., and IV. 37. Attaining Mukti at the final momnet of life is called Videha Mukti.

Comment: @Creator See also Sri Vidyaranya Swami's 'Pancadasi' (II. 97-106) for detailed discussion of this. Verse 97: "...all the worlds and all objects are reduced to a mere illusory appearance. What does it matter even if they still continue to appear?" and 'The water of a mirage does not soak the earth, so also, the unreal world does not disturb the oneness of reality.' (Swami Swahananda comment of verse 97)

Comment: Finally prarabdha never ends?? this is what I get till now.This clearly means that  you have to end your material life even after attaining a paramahansa upadhi or becoming a jeevan mukta? This feels like some sort of cheating by god in this cosmic game.

Comment: @Creator for an enlightened soul it ends when the body is given up. But for an enlightened soul, it is a mere mirage; it has no effect on them...